Facebook group posting Selenium
I've been working for the past months on this project that logins in a facebook account and should post a picture on a group.
Everything works just fine besides the final Post button which won't click.
The web browser is in french, i hope this isn't an issue.
def post_picture(driver, group_url, picture_path):
    logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Navigating to group discussion...")

    # Define XPaths used for locating elements
    XPATHS = {
        "Write": '//span[text()="Exprimez-vous..."]',
        "Post": '//div[@aria-label="Publier"]',
        "Photo": '//div[@aria-label="Photo / vidéo"]',
        "anonyme": '//input[@role="switch" and @type="checkbox"]',
        "ok": '//div[@aria-label="OK"]',
        "media_content": "//div[@aria-label='Contenu multimédia joint']",
        "file_input": "//input[@accept='image/*,image/heif,image/heic,video/*,video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/x-matroska,.mkv']",
        "join_group": '//div[@aria-label="Rejoindre le groupe"]',
        "plus": '//div[@aria-label="Insérez un emoji"]',

    }

    try:
        driver.get(group_url)
        try:
            join_group = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATHS["join_group"]))
        )
            join_group.click()
            logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Succesfully joined the group")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, XPATHS["Write"]))
            
        )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Failed to join the group")
        # Click the post box
        post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATHS["Write"]))
        )
        post_box.click()
        # Click the photo upload button
        photo = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATHS["Photo"]))
        )
        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Clicked on photo upload button.")

        # Upload the picture
        file_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPATHS["file_input"])
        file_input.send_keys(picture_path)
        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Uploaded the picture.")

        # Wait for picture to finish uploading
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, XPATHS["media_content"]))
        )
        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Verified the picture upload.")

        # Post the picture


        post_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATHS["Post"]))
            )
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(post_button).click().perform()


        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Picture posted successfully.")
        # Check if an error indicator element exists
        element_present = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/span/div/div[2]'))
        )
        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Error element detected after posting.")
        return False

    except TimeoutException:
        logging.info(f"{get_formatted_time()} Post successful without error element.")
        return True

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"{get_formatted_time()} Error during posting")
        return False

As you can see, i am using the action tool to try to click the button but this is still not working. Using actions, i am not getting any error but if i use post_button.click() and error pops up telling me that the element is not clickable at that point, an other element would receive the click.
While testing, i came up with a "solution" (in quotes because it doesn't really work) while trying out things.
For some reason, if i click the the button that lets me post in anonymous mode just before clicking the post button, the post button works.
        # Toggle the anonymous checkbox using JavaScript
        anonyme_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, strategy["anonyme"]))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", anonyme_button)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", anonyme_button)
        time.sleep(1)  # Give time for the UI to update

        # Click the OK button (ensure it's clickable)
        ok_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, strategy["ok"]))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ok_button)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ok_button)
    
        # Wait for the post button and click it
        post_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, strategy["Post"]))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",post_button)
        post_button.click()

Now here is the issue, not every group in which i want to post has the anonymous function.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Ok so, Im so freaking happy i finally found a solution after a very long time. It turns out i was checking for an element having area-label="Publier" but there were 2 itemes with the same area-label. So i just specified more instructions(role,tabindex) and it works

You neeed to update xpath of post_button button.
We can target it by its text like for English //*[text()="Post"] By using this method you can update XPath according to french and make it working

Can you clarify please ? Why do i need to update it ?
Even with the update i still get this error: ERROR - 11:29:39 Error during posting: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6 xlyipyv xuxw1ft">...</span> is not clickable at point (531, 1087). Other element would receive the click: <img draggable="false" alt="" class="x5yr21d xl1xv1r xh8yej3" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" src="blob:https://www.facebook.com/efee8c62-82f4-4232-a40f-0600377a6d1c">

I use that method to identify elements if I am unable to find static and reliable selector
It looks like another element overlapping button. But I think still you did not created right XPath
since I created multiple scripts for Facebook posting and I never got this error
You can use javascript to trigger click to solve this problem but first you need to verify XPATH is targeting right element

Thanks for the clarification. I did in fact check if the Xpath is the right element and it was. Clicking the button with java scritpt doesn't work for me.
When i first tested this script it was working perfectly. It's been like 2 weeks since it doesn't work so i think they updated something
